# how to pass val to val without these errors: Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, var

This is a topic selector made in `<a>` tag in php. Once user click on trigger, the function pass value from the original `<a>` tag to another `<input>` tag for display purpose. then when user submits form, ajaxForm is called out to handle the rest.

js.file:

```
function selectopic(topic_selector_name){        
 $('#topicidselected').val($(topic_selector_name).val());
 // alert ($('#topicidselected').val());
 $('#topicidselected').text($(topic_selector_name).val());
 $('#topicselected').text($(topic_selector_name).text());
}

$('.topicselect').click(function(){
selectopic($(this));
}); 

$('#newentryform').ajaxForm({
    target:  '#para1', 
    resetForm: true,     
    });
```

problem is, we suppose to have `$_POST={"entry":"blahblahblah","topicid":"122","date":"12\/06\/12","privacy":"onlyme"}`

but instead, it gives me `Notice: Undefined index: topicid in D:\wamp\www\projectdiary\diary\php\_newentry.php on line 2`

```
{"entry":"blahblahblah","topicid":null,"belongdate":"12\/06\/12","privacy":"onlyme"}
```

php.file:

```
$arr = array( 'entry' => $_POST['entry'], 'topicid' => $_POST['topicid'], 'date' => $_POST['date'], 'privacy' => $_POST['privacy']);
  echo "We have saved your entry, this is how it looks like: <br />";
      echo json_encode( $arr );
```

You can see in js.file I used alert to check the value after passed in. It is a correct number "122".

I'm a noob, I need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: What does the form look like?

Comment: Yes, THE HTML FORM! after checking the form agian, problem is solved now. I use a tag in form to get POST!!!! How stupid is that... I changed it to input, it is all back to normal now. Thanks for all your help. this is the most silly question ever. Please down vote me if you will feel better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you assigning the value to `topicselected` and setting the `text` property (not proper use, [see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/))? You're clicking `a` tags and getting the `val()` of them? See the docs there: http://api.jquery.com/val/ -- also not valid. Maybe I've misunderstood you?

I think you're trying harder than you have to, this could be accomplished in one line:

```
jQuery('.topicselect').click(function(){$('#topicidselected').val(this.rel);});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KNERB/

Comment: yes, using a tag is the biggest mistake ever. but change back to input, actually I think your line is very a-like to mine. the only difference is u use rel and i use val.   **$("#topicidselected").val($(topic_selector_name).val());**  BTW is there any advantages using rel?

Comment: Using `rel` as opposed to what? You could use data attributes, i.e. `this.data('id')`, tag would be `<a data-id="122">` -- no real difference between that and rel. Aside from a form element, no other tag should use the `value` property: this is not valid `<a value="123">`, nor is calling `this.val()` in a non-form element's click handler. Maybe you CAN do it (in certain browsers, in certain situations), but you shouldn't (ever) -- you should use `rel` or data attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the index is defined, if isnt put NULL

```
$_POST['entry'] = isset($_POST['entry']) ? $_POST['entry'] : NULL;
$_POST['topicid'] = isset($_POST['topicid']) ? $_POST['topicid'] : NULL;
$_POST['privacy'] = isset($_POST['privacy']) ? $_POST['privacy'] : NULL;
$_POST['date'] = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : NULL;

$arr = array( 'entry' => $_POST['entry'], 'topicid' => $_POST['topicid'], 'date' => $_POST['date'], 'privacy' => $_POST['privacy']);
  echo "We have saved your entry, this is how it looks like: <br />";
      echo json_encode( $arr );
```

Or disable the notice

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$arr = array( 'entry' => $_POST['entry'], 'topicid' => $_POST['topicid'], 'date' => $_POST['date'], 'privacy' => $_POST['privacy']);
  echo "We have saved your entry, this is how it looks like: <br />";
      echo json_encode( $arr );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `alert` suggests that you have successfully populated `#topicidselected` with a value, so my guess is the problem will be with the form. Check:

1. That the `input` tag you are setting a value on (`#topicidselected`) is actually part of the form that is being submitted - in other words, that it is nested inside the `<form>` tag where your other form elements reside.
2. That the `input` has the `name` attribute `topicid`: `<input name="topicid" id="topicidselected" value="" />`